Having an expandable legend item
I'm having trouble finding anything related to that so I'm trying to get some insights here.
Is there a way to build a graph (any graph, but let's take a bar graph as an example)  in way where part of the series items lay under 'Other', and on click on it, they expand? For example, In the following graph, having the circled items as part of 'Other', and only on click on it, expand it to be shown as in the picture. Notice that the example I gave is a static list of items, but in my case I can not rely
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Amounts of 15 Different Types of Fruits'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Fruits']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Amount'
        }
    },
    series: dataSeries 
    
});

Bar Graph Legend Items
I tried having a nested item list- didn't work. Searched documentation and didn't find any reference to that.

You can use linkedTo property to connect a couple of series. In the following example when you click Other in the legend it will show and hide a group of series gathered under Other series. I hope this is something you were looking for. Feel free to ask any further questions please!
API references:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.linkedTo
Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rjc0p2xf/
 {
  name: 'Other',
  id: 'other',
  data: [4]
}, {
  name: 'Limes',
  linkedTo: 'other',
  data: [3]
}


Thanks! It's not exactly answering my requirements. When it's not expanded, I want to have a bar that sums up all items linked to it- 'Others'. Then, when 'Other' is clicked, all items linked to it will be displayed on the graph as separated bars- instead of the 'Others' bar. Another click on 'Others' should revert back to a single bar that sums all items linked to it.

Unfortunately such functionality has not been implemented in Highcharts. Still you can create it by your own using load and legendItemClick events together with setData, and show & hide methods. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rvwfnq1L/ Please let me know what you think about this solution as we can still adjust it to your needs.

Thanks! It's heading there, but still not exactly what I want. My issue is that my data have too many items. Seeing al of it is not really friendly for the eye, yet I can't omit items. So I wanted to reduce it in a way where some of the data is shown by default, and the rest is under 'Other'. What you did is almost there, but I still want to hide completely (including from the legend) all items that are linked to 'Other' unless it was expanded.

Sure thing, to achieve that you should also update showInLegend option. Just like that: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/acfyxr41/

Thanks! Solving my issue. Is it possible to use the same solution for any type of graph?  Or at least for a vertical bar graph?

Of course, just change the chart.type property to column for example. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fzh05b71/ If you think that I have solved your problem, please mark my answer as the correct one. Thanks!

I was looking for a solution like so and couldn't find anything as well!
